# Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Contact]: [Contact]

Tags: apex

```
public with sharing class Apparel_PageController {

    public List<Trendsters_Order__c> orders{get;set;}
    public String contactId{get;set;}
    public Case objCase{get;set;}

    public Decimal totalAmount{get;set;}
    public Decimal cartSize{get;set;}
    public String currentProductId{get;set;}

    public List<Trendsterz_Inventory__c> inventries {get;set;}

    public List<Trendsters_Order__c> cart{get;set;}


    public Apparel_PageController(){
        totalAmount = 0;
        cartSize = 0;
        cart = new List<Trendsters_Order__c>();
        User objUser = [select ContactId 
                        from User 
                        where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
        contactId = objUser.ContactId;
        //contactId = '0037F00000a8HVg';
        objCase = new Case(ContactId=contactId);

        inventries = [select Id,Brand__c, Designer_Name__c, Design_Name__c, Price__c,Image_Url__c
                      from Trendsterz_Inventory__c 
                      LIMIT 10];    
    }

    public void fetchOrders(){

        orders = [SELECT Id,Name,Brand__c,Contact__c,Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.Email, 
                                            Designer_Name__c,Design_Name__c,Email__c,Price__c,Order_Status__c
                  FROM Trendsters_Order__c 
                  WHERE Contact__c = :contactId];

    }

    public void submitFeedback(){
        insert objCase;
    }

    public void addToCart(){        
        for(Trendsterz_Inventory__c inventry : inventries){
            if(currentProductId !=null && inventry.Id == currentProductId){
                Trendsters_Order__c order = new Trendsters_Order__c();
                system.debug('contactid -->'+contactId);
                order.Contact__c = contactId;
                order.Design_Name__c = inventry.Design_Name__c;
                order.Price__c= inventry.Price__c;
                                                          cart.add(order);
                break;
            }
        }
        cartSize = cart.size();
       // totalAmount = cart.size();
    }
    public void payProduct(){
              system.debug('cart -> ' + cart.size());
        insert cart;
    }


}
```

Comment: Error is preity clear. Contact is required and blank. Are you facing any challenge.

Comment: In my system debug....it is fetching Contact ID....

Comment: After sometime it showed success.....it was happening yesterday also.....it failed and then after sometime automatically it got success

Comment: You are getting ContactId always.

Comment: M really new on this....it's just been 1 week that I have started working on salesforce.....can u please explain...what could the error be?.....coz exactly as u said Contact Id is getting fetched...but then y Required field Missing error is coming?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility to consider is that you are checking the code using different logins (users).

The `User.ContactId` is populated for user's that have setup their login via [Self-Registration for Your Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_selfreg_page.htm&type=5) because that mechanism starts from a `Contact` and hooks up a `User` to that `Contact`. But it is not populated for users that have a standard login created by a System Administrator.

If that is the case, your page should just output a message such as "Only community users can use this page". Or the page logic should be otherwise reconsidered for that case.

Comment: Thanku so much....but it is from a registered user.

Comment: @SaniyaVirmani Ah OK.  One other thing to check is that there are no triggers or workflows on `Trendsters_Order__c` that are resetting the ContactId.

Comment: nop....@Keith C....there are no triggers and workflows

Comment: @KeithC Hi there! I've had this issue where I get the required field missing error on a specific field on a custom object. This field was deployed as a required field but was changes to not being required after a day. However, we're still getting this error once in a while on new records being inserted. I haven't been able to find out why this is happening. Please help if you have ideas as to what may be causing this. Thanks!